# Changing WordPress folder generates CSS issues?

Tags: directory

I'm moving my wordpress from `/test-blog/` to `/blog/`.

To do so I'm.

- Updating `siteurl` and `home` directly on the DB table `wp_options`.
- Updating the folder name for the blog on `.htaccess`.
- Renaming the folder from `/test-blog/` to `/blog/`.

I can access the wp-admin and so on but I noticed some styles are messed up. The posts styles are all messed up, they get modified.
The same with the /home page.

Styles that were applied before like the following, won't exist anymore, causing layout issues:

```css
.wp-block-post-template {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Those are defined inlined, like this:

```css
<style id='wp-block-post-template-inline-css'>
    .wp-block-post-template{list-style:none;margin-bottom:0; 
    ...truncated...
</style>
```

But for some reason they won't appear after renaming WP to a new folder name.

I'm not sure why those styles are not loaded on the new folder.
If I revert the changes then everything works ok again.

Where are those styles loading? Is there anything else I have to change when moving WP to a new folder?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently, I had to remove the `_transient_wp_core_block_css_files` record from the `wp_options` table on the database.

Mysteries of WordPress.

[Source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-block-styles-not-loading-in-frontend/).